# Cannot read property 'modalType' of undefined at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react and using Dan Park's solution 
https://medium.com/@danparkk/react-modals-scalable-customizable-neat-components-f2088d60f3d3
to design modal in my React project. But getting this error.

How can I try to debug it in react and why modalType is

modalRoot.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

/** Modal Components */
import LoginModal from '../../components/Modal/logInModal';
import SignupModal from '../../components/Modal/signUpModal';

/** Modal Type Constants */
import { LOGIN_MODAL, SIGNUP_MODAL } from '../../constants/ModalTypes';

const MODAL_COMPONENTS = {
  LOGIN_MODAL: LoginModal,
  SIGNUP_MODAL: SignupModal
};

const ModalContainer = (props) => {
  if (!props.modalType) {
    return null;
  }

  const SpecificModal = MODAL_COMPONENTS[props.modalType];

  return <SpecificModal />;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    modalType: state.modal.modalType
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ModalContainer);
```

reducers.js

```
/** Initial State */
const initialModalState = {
  modalType: null
};

/** Modal reducer */
export default function (state = initialModalState, action) {
  const newState = Object.assign({}, state);

  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_MODAL:
      console.log(action.modalType);
      newState.modalType = action.modalType;
      break;

    case HIDE_MODAL:
      return initialModalState;

    default:
      return state;
  }

  return newState;
}
```

EDIT: I am combining the reducer with react boilerplate like this:

Filename : app/reducers.js

```
/**
 * Combine all reducers in this file and export the combined reducers.
 */

import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux';

import globalReducer from 'containers/App/reducer';
import modal from './reducers/modal';
import languageProviderReducer from 'containers/LanguageProvider/reducer';

/*
 * routeReducer
 *
 * The reducer merges route location changes into our immutable state.
 * The change is necessitated by moving to react-router-redux@5
 *
 */

// Initial routing state
const routeInitialState = fromJS({
  location: null,
});

/**
 * Merge route into the global application state
 */
function routeReducer(state = routeInitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    case LOCATION_CHANGE:
      return state.merge({
        location: action.payload,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

/**
 * Creates the main reducer with the dynamically injected ones
 */
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    modal,
    route: routeReducer,
    global: globalReducer,
    language: languageProviderReducer,
    ...injectedReducers,
  });
}
```

Comment: can you please add the part where you have configured the reducer to store or the combineReducer part

Comment: @Kodanda Rama Durgarao poluri I am using react boilerplate and I Updated it in app/reducers.js. I edited the code

Comment: The error is that in your mapStateProps you need to pass a selector in fact I'm not even sure that you need to use a container here since you pass your modalType directly to your function.

Comment: @soupette what is the selector in this case

Answer (score 0):

It is updated by changing the selector
Updated code

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    modalType: state.modalType
  };
};
```